# How to use predefined function (e.g. ==, tail) on my custom data type in Haskell?

Tags: function, haskell, typeclass

I'm new to haskell and nothing I've read online really helped me with this. My assignment is to implement a typeclass *VEC* that has a function *factor* which either calculates the multiplication of two Integers or performs the dot product of two matrices if the user input wasn't two numbers but instead two lists of integers of type vector. My code looks as follows:

```
data Vector = VECTOR [Int] deriving (Show, Eq)
class VEC a where
    factor :: a -> a -> a
instance VEC Int where
    factor a b = a*b
instance VEC Vector where
    factor xs [] = 0
    factor xs ys = (head xs) * (head ys) + factor (tail xs) (tail ys)
```

I assumed the Vectors were of type `[Int]` but now I'm not so sure, since I get the following error message when trying to compile the code using Hugs:

```
Hugs> :l kdp  
ERROR file:kdp.hs:7 - Type error in instance member binding  
*** Term           : []  
*** Type           : [a]  
*** Does not match : Vector
```

So my questions would be: What does the first line actually mean? It was given along with the assignment and I've seen many similar definitions of data types but none with this particular pattern. And then how do I fix the problem of not being able to use predefined functions such as `tail` or in the above error case comparing a list of Integers with my custom data type? My guess is I have to define the operations on my own but I couldn't figure out how to do that.

Comment: Hugs is deprecated, use ghc: https://www.haskell.org/hugs/

Comment: `Vector` is implemented in *terms* of lists, but it is a distinct type *from* `[Int]`. `newtype Vector = VECTOR [Int]` would be preferable. You still need to wrap/unwrap the list to work with it in your code, but at runtime the wrapper is discarded so there is overhead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you write an instance for a class like

```
class C a where
  method :: a -> a
```

you replace all of the parameter appearances (`a`) with the type you are writing instance for. For example in your case:

```
{-# LANGUAGE InstanceSigs #-}
instance VEC Vector where
    factor :: Vector -> Vector -> Vector
    factor _ _ = undefined
```

So you cannot match arguments of type `Vector` with pattern `[]` nor use `head` nor `tail` functions on it as they are working on lists. However, your `Vector` consists of lists, so you can simply unpack it:

```
instance VEC Vector where
    factor _ (Vector []) = Vector [0] -- you need to return Vector as well
    factor (Vector xs) (Vector ys) =
      let Vector [x] = factor (Vector $ tail xs) (Vector $ tail ys)
      in Vector [(head xs) * (head ys) + x]
```

This is very ugly and partial tho, you can use some builtin `Data.List` machinery to make it more sexy:

```
instance VEC Vector where
  factor (Vector xs) (Vector ys) =
    Vector [sum (zipWith (*) xs ys)]
```

---

As you are using `deriving (Show, Eq)`, the `==` operator should just work.

Comment: Worth noting that the instance you wrote can easily be generalized to `VEC a => VEC [a]`; then you can use the `GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving` extension to generate the instance for `newtype Vector = VECTOR [Int] deriving (Show, Eq, VEC)`.

Comment: `instance VEC a => VEC [a] where factor xs ys = [sum $ zipWith (*) xs ys]`. Then `instance VEC Vector where factor (VECTOR xs) (VECTOR ys) = VECTOR (factor xs ys)`, if you don't want to use the extension.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I'm still quite unsure about some things though. For one, shouldn't the function always return an `Int` since that's the result of a dot product? And then I wanted to try out your solutions and got error message _Undefined data constructor "Vector"_... indeed, Hugs is outdated and generates bad error messages but my lecturer recommended it for its light weight and since it suffices for our purposes. On repl.it, the error message is: main.hs:7:17: error: Not in scope: data constructor `Vector'. Perhaps you meant variable `factor' (line 3)

Comment: So I have a feeling I'm very close... I got the program to compile and load by using *VECTOR* instead of *Vector* where I assumed it to be appropriate and now Integer multiplication works if I type in something such as `factor 2 3::Int` it gives me 6. If I try out the vector product `factor [1,2,3] [2,3,4]::Vector` I get a ERROR - Type error in type annotation
*** Term           : factor [1,2,3] [2,3,4]
*** Type           : [a]
*** Does not match : Vector. I have a feeling the code might be correct but my input is not.

Comment: @CarlMariusDaub But your class defines `factor` to have type `VEC a => a -> a -> a`. You can't change the type from one instance to the next. You can provide a dot-product-*like* definition for `factor`, but not a dot-product definition itself, which would have type `Vector -> Vector -> Int`.

Comment: I applaud the use of instance sigs

Answer (score 2):

You can generalize your type class to take *two* type variables to accommodate the two different operations of integer multiplication and vector dot products. This requires two GHC-specific extensions, though, precluding your use of Hugs.

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses, FunctionalDependencies #-}

-- a -> b means that the second type is uniquely determined by the
-- first. Without it, you would need explicitly type an expression
-- involving factor.
class VEC a b | a -> b  where
    factor :: a -> a -> b

instance VEC Int Int where
    -- a ~ Int, b ~ Int
    factor x y = x * y

-- newtype instead of data, for efficiency if nothing else
newtype Vector = VECTOR [Int] deriving (Show, Eq)

instance VEC Vector Int where
    -- a ~ Vector, b ~ Int
    factor (VECTOR xs) (VECTOR ys) = sum $ zipWith (*) xs ys


main = do
  print $ factor (3 :: Int) 3
  print $ factor (VECTOR [1,2,3]) (VECTOR [4,5,6])
```

Without the functional dependency, you would have to write

```
main = do
    print (factor (3 :: Int) 3 :: Int)
    print (factor (VECTOR [1,2,3]) (VECTOR [4,5,6]) :: Int)
```

Comment: I like this one